# Laravel collection - only() to main array and subarray

Tags: arrays, laravel, recursion, collections

I have collection (from database with complicated query), and I'm trying to get only few values of it via ->only() method but it doesn't work.

Collection:

```
0 => array:4 [
  "id" => 1
  "start_date" => "2018-07-07 14:00:00"
  "end_date" => "2018-07-07 15:00:00"
  "child" => array:5 [
    "id" => 1
    "name" => "Mr. Davin Conroy Sr."
    "email" => "prempel@example.com"
    "created_at" => "2018-07-06 22:28:16"
    "updated_at" => "2018-07-06 22:28:16"
  ]
]
1 => array:4 [
  "id" => 2
  "start_date" => "2018-07-07 15:00:00"
  "end_date" => "2018-07-07 16:00:00"
  "child" => array:5 [
    "id" => 1
    "name" => "Mr. Davin Conroy Sr."
    "email" => "prempel@example.com"
    "created_at" => "2018-07-06 22:28:16"
    "updated_at" => "2018-07-06 22:28:16"
  ]
```

My code:

```
    $subset = $monitorList->map(function ($monitor) {
        return collect($monitor->toArray())
            ->only(['id', 'start_date', 'end_date', 'child.name', 'child.email'])
            ->all();
    });
```

But it lost child.name. What could be the solution for this problem?

```
0 => array:3 [
  "id" => 1
  "start_date" => "2018-07-07 14:00:00"
  "end_date" => "2018-07-07 15:00:00"
]
1 => array:3 [
  "id" => 2
  "start_date" => "2018-07-07 15:00:00"
  "end_date" => "2018-07-07 16:00:00"
]
```

Comment: You have converted it to an array, its no longer a Model instance and that is why you cannot use dot `.` to get the values ( I guess). You can definitely get the value already when making the query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
$subset = $monitorList->map(function ($monitor) {
     $data = $monitor->only('id', 'start_date', 'end_date');
     $data['child'] = $monitor->child->only('name', 'email');
     return $data;
});
```

In you case more best practice to get only that data, which need.

```
$monitorList = Motor::with('child:id,name,email')
    ->get(['id', 'id_user', 'start_date', 'start_date']);
```

You can also use this code in your case

```
$subset = $monitorList->map(function ($monitor) {
     $monitor->child->makeHidden('updated_at', 'created_at', 'id');
     return $monitor;
});
```

For good practice you can use

```
$monitorList = Motor::with('child:id,name,email')
    ->get(['id', 'id_user', 'start_date', 'start_date']);

$subset = $monitorList->map(function ($monitor) {
     $monitor->child->makeHidden('id');
     return $monitor;
});
```

Comment: Which solution you use??

Comment: first, second option unfortunately shows 'child' as null. Maybe because I have a little more complicated query

Comment: child `null` because does not select foreign key correspond relation. You can use this it is more perfect solution `$monitorList = Motor::with('child:id,name,email')
    ->get(['id', 'id_user', 'start_date', 'start_date']);`

Comment: try it it will work, if does not work change `id_user` correspond key

Comment: nice, it worked but now I'm still unable to hide 'id' from child, any possibilities to hide it too?

Comment: Yes but it is no good solution. You Must be in `User` model define `protected $hidden = ['id'];`

Comment: Sometimes it will be needed, so i stick with first option

Comment: That case can use `makeVisible('id')` in `$user` object

Comment: I suggest you use `combination of second and last solutions`

Answer (score 1):

it seems like the only method can't get nested parameters so you should use your own transformation like :

```
$subset = $monitorList->map(function ($monitor) {
    $value = collect($monitor->toArray())->only('id', 'start_date', 'end_date')->all();
    $value['child'] = collect($monitor->child->toArray())->only('name', email')->all();      
    return $value;
});
```